# Ag-grid GroupCheckboxSelectionCallback does not conditionally work for groupRows

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

```
`public groupRowRendererParams: any = {
    checkbox: true,
    // Below does not work
    /*
    checkbox: (params) => {
    if (params.value === "test") {
    return true;
    }
    return false;
}
*/
}`
```

Please find the below test link:

https://plnkr.co/edit/nbM4VBgLnH1maO2l?open=app.component.ts (Please look at line 70)

checkbox display does not work with the GroupCheckboxSelectionCallback when using groupRows